# Cannot match sensor with sensors.conf chip

Tags: sensors

On my system, there is a pmbus device (dps1600).

I want to change the label for sensors output.

My config file `/etc/sensors.d/sensors.conf`:

```
bus "i2c-11" "i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)"
bus "i2c-12" "i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)"
bus "i2c-13" "i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)"

chip "dps1600-i2c-11-58"
    label in1 "PSU Vin"
    label in2 "PSU Vout"
    label fan1 "PSU Fan"
    label temp1 "PSU temp1"
    label temp2 "PSU temp2"
    label temp3 "PSU temp3"
    label power1 "PSU Pin"
    label power2 "PSU Pout"
    label curr1 "PSU Iin"
    label curr2 "PSU Iout"
```

My sensors result remains the same.

```
root@sonic:/# sensors "dps1600-i2c-11-58"
dps1600-i2c-11-58
Adapter: i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)
vin:         +216.75 V
vout1:       +12.06 V
fan1:        4576 RPM
temp1:        +28.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
temp2:        +40.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
temp3:        +34.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
pin:         255.75 W  (max =   2.13 kW)
pout1:       236.50 W  (max =   1.92 kW)
iin:          +1.20 A  (max = +11.84 A)
iout1:       +19.47 A  (max = +140.00 A, crit max = +149.00 A)
```

I try to change a little bit:

```
chip "dps1600-i2c-*-58"
    label in1 "PSU Vin"
    label in2 "PSU Vout"
    label fan1 "PSU Fan"
    label temp1 "PSU temp1"
    label temp2 "PSU temp2"
    label temp3 "PSU temp3"
    label power1 "PSU Pin"
    label power2 "PSU Pout"
    label curr1 "PSU Iin"
    label curr2 "PSU Iout"
```

It works:

```
root@sonic:/# sensors "dps1600-i2c-11-58"
dps1600-i2c-11-58
Adapter: i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)
PSU Vin:     +216.50 V
PSU Vout:    +12.05 V
PSU Fan:     4576 RPM
PSU temp1:    +28.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
PSU temp2:    +40.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
PSU temp3:    +34.0°C  (high = +110.0°C)
PSU Pin:     255.75 W  (max =   2.13 kW)
PSU Pout:    234.75 W  (max =   1.92 kW)
PSU Iin:      +1.20 A  (max = +11.84 A)
PSU Iout:    +19.53 A  (max = +140.00 A, crit max = +149.00 A)
```

Why does the first one fail?

==== update ====

I found that three adapter have the same name, which might be the root cause.

```
root@sonic:/# cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-11/name
i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)
root@sonic:/# cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-12/name
i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)
root@sonic:/# cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-13/name
i2c-3-mux (chan_id 0)
```

How can I avoid this?